# Would Chlorosian photosynthesizers produce chlorine or oxygen?

Tags: chemistry, biochemistry

Chloros is a world with a huge amount of sulfur. Because sulfates displace halogens in alkali metal salts, fluorine and chlorine in Chloros aren't all locked up in rocks; instead, the oceans are a dilute mixture of hydrochloric and hydrofluoric acid.

The native organisms still rely mostly on water (it's *dilute* acid, after all), so water is available as a hydrogen source for photosynthesis. But with plenty of HCl around, would they actually use water for photosynthesis?

Early photosynthesizers on Earth used hydrogen sulfide, because it's less tightly bound than water, and only evolved oxygen, water-consuming photosynthesis to avoid the bottleneck of low hydrogen sulfide supply. Would Chlorosian organisms be likely to switch to HCl instead, producing chlorine as a byproduct? Or is that sufficiently difficult that they would just consume water to produce oxygen anyway, just like Earthlings?

Comment: @John, no, it really isn't; which reaction is more energetically favorable is an objective fact. All else being equal, if stealing hydrogens from water is cheaper than stealing them from HCl, then organisms that release oxygen will outcompete organisms that release chlorine--and vice-versa.

Comment: the reason oxygen is used is because it is far  Far more common even on your planet, Chlorine is already abundant in plant chloroplasts and they don't use it. you drastically overestimate the importance of efficiency in photosynthesis, plant photosynthesis is rather poor compared other forms, it won because it was the from the lucked out to occur in a a eukaryote first.

Comment: @John The whole point of the question is that abundance isn't an issue--there is more than enough HCl to go around, *if it makes energetic sense*. Chloride ions are abundant in plants (and in us), but not in association with hydrogen. They aren't acidic, and just oxidizing chloride is pointless--the goal is to extract hydrogen. And all the other forms of photosynthesis on Earth use relatively rare substrates--plant photosynthesis won out because it can happen *anywhere*. If H2S were in unlimited supply, it would've won.

Comment: No the point is to extract hydrogen ions, which are bound to oxygen, even in HCl, HCl acid is chlorine ions and hydronium ions. the hydrogen is bound to oxygen. Cl is just an ion in both cases.

Comment: @John So the question still stands--is it easier to extract hydrogens from water, releasing oxygen, or to extract hydrogens from hydronium ions and release chlorine, or to extract hydrogen from hydronium and release hypochlorous acid?

Comment: It releases oxygen in both cases, the only question is whether chlorine can also act as a electron acceptor, which it can, so it can make oxygen and chlorine or just oxygen  but it cannot make just chlorine. but again which is dominate on your planet is up to you, energetics on this small of a difference is not a good predictor of evolutionary success.

Comment: @John I do not see why oxygen would necessarily be released along with chlorine. Sounds like you have background knowledge sufficient to explain that in a full answer, rather than just in comments, though.

Comment: photosynthesis does not pull one hydrogen ion off water it pulls all the hydrogen off of it,  so you get oxygen from water or hydrochloric acid, chlorine can also act as an electron acceptor just like oxygen at the end this makes the pathway more complex but that is not really a hinderance, different forms of photosynthesis are kluge enough for it not to matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136413/discussion-between-logan-r-kearsley-and-john).

Comment: You have to bear in mind, this is photosynthesis. The best system isn't that which has the lowest energy barrier, it's whichever system captures the most energy. Also, whatever photosynthetic system works first will probably win out by first mover advantage.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Empirically, that seems to not be true; photosynthesis in the real world is almost never energy-limited, and is not optimized for capturing the most energy; it's optimized for *synthesizing* useful biomolecules. But there is still an incentive to minimize the amount of energy that must be gathered for any single reaction; oxygenic photosynthesizers have a whole second photosystem *just* for splitting water, which isn't necessary in non-oxygenic photosynthesizers. It's likely such an expensive system wouldn't have evolved if H2S availability was not a limiting factor.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley Disagree. Photosynthesis is primarily for energy capture. That's its purpose. Whatever gets synthesised along the way is merely a means to that end. Animals synthesise all manner of useful molecules and need no photosynthesis to do it. And in any event, the main point is that the exact size of the energy barrier is not important, within reason (the produced molecules need to be stable enough to 'handle'). The bigger the thermodynamic barrier, the more energy you get by actually doing it. You wouldn't photosynthesise molecules with a virtually nil energy reaction, would you?

Comment: In other words, there's a countervailing incentive to maximise the energy gap.

Comment: @SeanOConnor *Most* of what plants synthesize is not used by them for energy storage--it's structural. The fact that plants' structural elements happen to be usable as energy sources to heterotrophs is irrelevant to the plants. Animals synthesize all sorts of molecules without *photo*synthesis because they have other ways of getting energy. Just like chemoautotrophs synthesize all sorts of molecules without photon energy. And if none of those other sources of energy were available, then yes, photosynthesis would be used to produce molecules with arbitrarily low energy requirements.

Comment: @LoganR.Kearsley But structural elements cost energy. Everything bar photosynthesis costs energy.  A structural element (or indeed, any biomolecule or biomaterial) is just more money deposited in the bank as far as thermodynamics is concerned. If plants' structural elements weren't expensive in energy, they'd just form them out of the nutrients they absorb from the earth. Chemotrophs can only exist because phototrophs have captured energy to begin with. Saying a molecule is synthetically useful is just a synonym for 'it's a high energy species'. That's how it works in man's synthetic chem too.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Indeed, structural elements do cost energy; but storing energy is *not their purpose*; hence, if they can made more cheaply, it is advantageous to do so. And yes, if they could form them for free, they *would*. That's my whole *point*. And chemoautotrophs have no dependence on photosynthetic life. For example, methanogens which react hydrogen and/or H2S with CO or CO2 from geological sources to produce the energy for carbon fixation have no dependence on any product of photosynthetic life, and similar organisms must have existed prior to the evolution of photosynthesis.

Comment: You've overthought this. All organisms require either the acquisition or production of high energy molecules. Without them, no biosynthesis can be sustained. That is the purpose of photosynthesis. The production of high energy molecules by photosynthesis is the purpose, not a drawback.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Again, that's not an empirically supportable position. Carbohydrates are not inherently high-energy molecules; it's the availability of oxygen that makes them such a good source of energy. But photosynthesis existed long before *oxygenic* photosynthesis--precisely because the point, for a plant, is *not* primarily to store energy, and producing high-energy oxygen was an unjustifiable waste as long as other hydrogen sources were sufficiently abundant.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, I would want to look at aqueous thermochemistry data for this, but all I can find references for is gas phase thermochemistry. However, if we run with that, we've got the following energy barriers to work with:

- HCl -92.31kJ/mol
- H2O -285.82kJ/mol
- HClO -74.48kJ/mol

I have included HClO because gaseous chlorine spontaneously reacts with water to form HCl and HClO.

(Just for reference, the heat of formation of HF is -272.55kJ/mol--getting two hydrogens out of that is almost twice as expensive as getting it out of water, so that ain't happening! Nobody's gonna be breathing fluorine here.)

So, how much energy does it take to get 2 hydrogens from various reactions? As a baseline, splitting water and releasing oxygen requires 285.82kJ/mol, plus metabolic inefficiency:

H2O + 285.82kJ/mol -> $\frac{1}{2}$O2 + H2

What about exchanging a chlorine for a hydrogen, converting water and HCl into hypochlorous acid and hydrogen?

H2O + HCl + 303.65kJ/mol -> HClO + H2

Looks like that won't happen, because it costs more! And directly splitting HCl?

2HCl + 184.62kJ/mol -> CL2 + H2

That turns out to look considerably cheaper than splitting water! So yeah, Chlorosians should produce chlorine gas! Except... chlorine reacts with water. Based on the data I have, the reaction

H2O + Cl2 -> HClO + HCl

should consume 119.04kJ/mol, which explains why producing hypochlorous acid directly looks disfavorable here. But in reality, that reaction actually does occur spontaneously, so I have to assume that there are solvation effects or something that make this analysis incorrect.

So, it kinda looks like Chlorosians would really produce hypochlorous acid rather than chlorine gas or oxygen. But... exposure to sunlight causes hypochlorous acid to dissociate into HCl and free oxygen. So, they end up getting to an oxygen atmosphere in the end after all!

EDIT: According to [Chloride Oxidation as an Alternative to the Oxygen Evolution Reaction on HxWO3 Photoelectrodes](https://www.osti.gov/pages/servlets/purl/1780871) producing chlorite from aqueous Cl- and H+ ions requires a slightly higher electrode potential than electrolysing water--so it seems that Chlorosian plants would be better of just using water as their hydrogen source, and Chlorosian animals will therefore definitely end up breathing oxygen.

Comment: HCl would not be molecule in question, hydrochloric acid is a Cl- ion and a H3O+ ion, HClO is a different acid.

Comment: @John So, can you actually write an answer?

Comment: I can't a good answer would take more time than I have right now, but I can help, these may be useful, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1367593115000022 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8621363/

Answer (score 1):

### It's practicality vs fun

The thermodynamic comparison you are looking for is here:

6CO2 + 6H2O -> C6H12O6 + 6O2
Vs
6CO2 + 12HCl -> C6H12O6 + 6Cl2

Note that while this is not the actual reaction in either system, it can be used due to Hess's Law (or whatever the free energy equivalent is called).

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation), you get that there is a difference of 12* 95 - 6 * 237  = 1140 - 1422 = 282 kJ/mol. The other species cancel out.

That's a trifling difference for a reaction involving 12 or 18 reactant species.

Photosynthesis, unlike every other biosynthetic reaction, is costless in energy, so given that you have a) more water, and b) known photosystems for oxygen, water is the choice that maximises the free energy of the author.

The limits in this case are scarcity of feedstock, and preventing unwanted side reactions in the starting reagents or waste products.

But either is credible in a sci fi book and chlorine is arguably more 'fun'.

PS Forget hypochlorous acid, it spontaneously disproportionates at anything except infinitesimal concentrations. It's only really a transitional species.